# Adobe Air - Change language

Tags: installation, language

How to change the language of Adobe Air? Currently the text during the [installation dialog](http://www.robertnyman.com/images/0806/adobe-air-installation-dialog.jpg) is displayed in German and I'd like to have it in English.

(Is there a way to change it or do I need to install an english Adobe Air version?)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to change the language once Adobe Air is installed. I'd recommend uninstalling the German version and installing the English version.

Comment: How to download the english version? I get redirected to the German version by visiting the download page at http://get.adobe.com/air/

Comment: In the lower left corner of the page, there is a "Choose your region" link. I tried setting mine to United States, then Germany, but when I went back to the Air download page, it defaulted back to United States. You might encounter a different result though. If that fails, try clearing your cookies.